# Finding day of the year

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the day of the year after you enter a date. I have a way that works but it is not the best way it seems.

I ask for the date using a Scanner object then send it through to a method where it checks what day of the year it is.

```
public static int theDay(int month, int day, int year)
{
    int numDay = day;

    /* Code here to check for leap year */

    for(int i = 1; i < month; i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
           case 1:
             numDay += 31;
             break;
           case 2:
             numDay += 28;
             break;
           case 3:
             numDay += 31;
             break;
           ...
           ... //goes until case 12
           ...
        }
    }

    return numDay;
}
```

I cannot use Calendar, LocalDate, arrays, and anything my teacher hasn't taught us yet. So just loops would be OK, I believe. As mentioned, this works and I get the correct day. But what would be a better way of doing this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on what you're using:

**Standard Java libraries, before Java 8**

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
// Just to avoid corner cases
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);
int dayOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

**Joda Time**

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
int dayOfYear = date.getDayOfYear();
```

**Java 8, using `java.time`**

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
int dayOfYear = date.getDayOfYear();
```

**Coding it yourself**

(Now that we know that's what you need to do.)

Your current approach is okay, if you really need to do this yourself. You can do it without a loop though:

```
int daysInFebruary = ...; // Leap year calculation

switch (month)
{
    case 1:
        break; // Nothing to do
    case 2:
        numDay += 31; // Just add January
        break;
    case 3:
        numDay += 31 + daysInFebruary; // Add January and February
        break;
    case 4:
        numDay += 31 + daysInFebruary + 31; // Add January to March
        break;
    case 5:
        numDay += 31 + daysInFebruary + 31 + 30; // Add January to April
        break;
    // etc
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month: " + month);
}
```

That's more efficient, but I'd consider it less readable than the code you've already got.

It would be *much* cleaner to do this with an array, mind you - you could have one array with the lengths of each month, and another with the cumulative lengths of each month (0, 31, 59 etc). Add a special case for leap years, and Bob's your uncle. But if you're not allowed to use arrays...

Comment: I cannot use Calendar or LocalDate as my teacher does not want us to use anything we haven't learned yet. No arrays either.

Comment: @yayu: I think you should have specified this in your question

Comment: @yayu: And you didn't think to mention that in the question? The obvious answer is "don't reinvent the wheel"... if you're going to want something *other* than that, you should say so.

Comment: Regarding your new answer, I had it like that at first. Unfortunately, my teacher didn't accept it as it was not the best way. I asked him exactly what he wanted but gave no clues. I didn't mention it as I didn't think it was better than what I posted.

Comment: @yayu: And again, you didn't think to mention this? Given that you *can't* do it the "best" way (i.e. not writing the logic yourself at all) and you don't have any requirements for the "best" way, I suggest you just stop. You've got working code, it's reasonably readable (although you don't need case 12). If your teacher doesn't accept it, and doesn't give you clear reasons for that, then it's your *teacher* who is at fault, not you.

Comment: Well, that sucks. Thank you for your time and replies and sorry for not mentioning stuff.